# MySQL not throwing some errors in prepared statement

Tags: mysql, errors, prepared-statement

If I run the following query:

```
DELETE FROM `table` where `id` = '123%7D';
```

*Notice the gibberish at the end of the where clause*

I get the following error

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '123%7D'

Which is the expected behavior since I'm running a MySQL (5.7.33-log) database on strict mode.

**BUT**

If I run the same query on a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM "delete from `table` where `id` = ?;";
SET @id = '1234%7D';
EXECUTE stmt USING @id;
```

The query runs fine without any error, which in my view is not expected behavior

My question is, how can I make prepared queries throw the same errors that they would throw as if they where not prepared?

Thanks in advance.

My **@@sql_mode** value is:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: What is the data type of ``id``?

Comment: @mustaccio The `ìd` column is a `int(10) unsigned`

Comment: Where did the string come from?  It looks like a "url-encoded" string.  That would turn `}` into `%7D` to avoid difficulties when used in a URL string.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, it did come from a URL. But for the scope of my question, any form of gibberish in the string reproduces the same results.

Comment: Dig back further and find out where the `}` comes from.